# ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver after migration to liferay 7 from liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-7

I get below error in console when deploying each portlet after migration to liferay 7 which was working fine with liferay 6.2

`ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver cannot be found by MAIPF_MyAccount-portlet_7.0.0.1
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IDPLaptop/MAIPF2012_dev_VR7`

Comment: What connection pool are you using? Did you add the JDBC driver for MS sql?

Comment: Hikari Cp is the pool  .I have added the jdbc driver in the tomcat lib folder.Should i add it to each portlet?

Comment: Can you past the JSBC configuration from portal-ext.properties or the JNDI configuration? Are you using the service builder?

Comment: jdbc.default.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IDPLaptop/LiferayDEV_VR7
    jdbc.default.username=
    jdbc.default.password=

Comment: Yes i use service builder

Comment: sqljdbc42.jar is the jar i added to tomcat lib folder

Comment: I assume that this is a driver that worked for you in 6.2 with the same DB and the only changed thing in the mix is Liferay 7. Could you upload the full error log somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156812/discussion-between-srigin-and-miroslav-ligas).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you fell into a common issue I keep seeing on StackOverflow when people try to upgrade to Liferay 7: libraries within the server's lib are not visible for all portlets.

With the ability to code OSGi modules,if one moves their portlet to an OSGi bundle, they need to keep track of the dependencies that module require.

As the jar you are using is not a bundle, you will need to create a uber bundle or use compileInclude to create a fat jar for your module.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 7, out of the box, does only support open source databases. As you state that you're using Service Builder, you might need to install [Antonio's SQLServer integration](https://www.dontesta.it/en/2016/04/19/liferay-7-ce-how-to-add-support-for-sql-server-db/) or move to the commercial offering, Liferay DXP.

Check Victor's answer as well. I commonly use open source databases and DXP anyways, so the nitty-gritty-details that are hidden here are only my theoretical knowledge, I rarely get to experience this in practice.

Comment: good point, my guess is that he will need to check both depending on how he is using it. As he says it is just a portlet, I guess he is calling the DB directly, otherwise the portal as a whole would have issues...OP needs to clarify this point. @srigin any comments?

Comment: well, you can have portal on one database and service-builder components on another. Thus it's possible to  operate portal without any problems, while a random portlet might have problems persisting its data. Calling the DB directly might impose problems as of the OSGi classloading - you can't necessarily assume that you automatically have all of tomcat's classes available: A module in Liferay 7 has its own OSGi classloader.

Comment: I don't get your point , is not that exactly what I mentioned? ..I was not desagreeing, just that it would be worth checking both-as you also did...the OP would need to help us helping him..

Comment: I guess I was just answering, rambling, whatever went through my head, @Victor. Didn't mean to imply anything, and I didn't read your answer again when I commented. As OP is mentioning using service builder, there's this additional assumption that comes in: When you declare an additional DB in service builder, you're not manually going after this database, but rather have everything wrapped in Liferay - that was what I was about to say. I'd *expect* this scenario to be covered by Liferay, but didn't crosscheck. Plus, with SQLServer not being supported OOTB, it's a questionable expectation.